# angularjs routing not working in proprietary browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, jboss, single-page-application

First, let me say you will not be able to reproduce my problem unless you also are working in a healthcare situation using the latest athenaPractice EMR.

I just don't have any direction on where to troubleshoot this problem and looking for suggestions for what information or settings I should be checking.

I have an AngularJS SPA set up that routes 100% fine in a regular Chrome browser window locally served (http-server installed via npm). I can load the main app page by URL (`localhost:port/app`, which redirects to `/app/#!`) and I can load the subpage by URL (`localhost:port/app/#!/page`). I can do it with or without a trailing `/`. I can navigate from one view to the other by links on the page. Works great.

But I have a problem when I put it in the server location (which, if it's relevant, has a path longer than /app/ from the `//localserver/` root), and load the file through the EMR (which is running Chromium). (Files are loaded in the EMR by adding a specially formatted file that links all included items in a form, which in the case of HTML files, is just a URL to a resource: `//localserver/directory/subdirectory/app/#!/page`). It loads fine the first time, but if I try to load separately a different page (`//localserver/directory/subdirectory/app/#!/`, for example), it shows the currently open page. It's almost like both instances of the browser are the same browser window and it doesn't bother to load a new window for the URL with the same address up to the `#!`. I can navigate from one page to another by links but not by loading from the root address, and if I navigate under one "form", and click back to the other one, it's also been navigated, hence why I think it's only one instance of the window.

I tried HTML5 routing with no success since this is running in a JBoss 7.x server and I have had a very hard time finding any documentation that even comes close to matching the files I see on the server for URL rewriting access. (I have found instructions that reference files that don't exist in our installation, so I don't know if this has been customized by the application provider, or what.)

I don't have access to developer tools, console, or even the address bar through the EMR.

Any suggestions on where to go with troubleshooting this?

Edit to add: Might be worth noting that I have tried ngRoute and ui-router both with the same results.

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#base-href-constraints

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't directly answer the problem but it's definitely something to keep in mind. I'm currently trying to make the undertow-handlers.conf correctly rewrite URLs but having trouble. (navigation works with HTML5 style urls, hard reload doesn't...)  If I reach a solution I'll be sure to update this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working correctly. I don't know what the root cause in the EMR is, but it was treating each loaded route of the SPA as part of the same instance using `#!` routes. Getting HTML5 routing working solved the issue.

After fighting with Undertow for a day and having no feedback on why my rules weren't working, I ended up using [Tuckey's URL Rewrite](https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). It helpfully logs what input it was comparing against what which allowed me to see where my first attempts at rules went wrong, and edit them accordingly until they worked.

This required three file changes in the `WEB-INF` directory inside the application's `.war` directory. (There are various META-INF and WEB-INF directories all over in this setup but using this one worked in the specific deployment I'm working in now, namely our demo server.)

1. Create a `/lib` directory inside `WEB-INF` and put `urlrewritefilter-4.0.4.jar` in it (downloaded from [the Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tuckey/urlrewritefilter/4.0.4))
2. Put the example `urlrewrite.xml` into `WEB-INF` and adapt it with necessary rules.  For the root page of our SPA and the first route, the custom rules I inserted look something like this:

```
    <rule match-type="regex" enabled="true">
        <condition type="request-filename" operator="notfile" />
        <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">(\.html|\.js|\.css)</condition>
        <from>^/FormsFolder/subfolder/app/$</from>
        <to last="true">/FormsFolder/subfolder/app/index.html</to>
    </rule>

    <rule match-type="regex" enabled="true">
        <condition type="request-filename" operator="notfile" />
        <condition type="request-uri" operator="notequal">(\.html|\.js|\.css)</condition>
        <from>^/FormsFolder/subfolder/app/route1/$</from>
        <to last="true">/FormsFolder/subfolder/app/index.html</to>
    </rule>
```

3. Add the Tuckey Rewrite Filter to `web.xml`:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>confPath</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <!-- This configures how often to check for an update to urlrewrite.xml -->
        <param-name>confReloadCheckInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>60</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <!-- This configures what detail level of messages to log. TRACE was useful to 
        figure things out but DEBUG or WARN is probably more appropriate for production -->
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>TRACE</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Lastly I had to update the `index.html` of the SPA to include the base tag, *before* all the stylesheet links and javascript script includes so that they route correctly. For the demo server, mine looks something like `<base href="/demo/ws/FormsFolder/subfolder/app/">` but will have to be updated to publish to the live server.

Hopefully this is helpful if anyone else is trying to configure HTML5 routing on a similar JBoss server.